# Cannot import name YearExact

Tags: django-1.8

**Cannot import name YearExact**

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/schedule/open-bill-schedule/
Django Version: 1.8.6
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name YearExact
Exception Location: /home/tungsten554/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/functions/datetime.py in <module>, line 9
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.10
Python Path:    
['/home/tungsten554/EsselUtilityWeb/esselutilities',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/tungsten554/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
Server time:    Wed, 19 Oct 2016 10:58:30 +0530
```

Comment: Can you post the associated code? Where are you importing from? It should be `from django.db.models.lookups import YearExact`.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/db/models/functions/datetime/ , hope this will help you for more help please post your code.